# What is reflow and repaint in these steps Styles -> Layout -> Paint -> Composite

Tags: css

In [this article](https://medium.com/outsystems-experts/how-to-achieve-60-fps-animations-with-css3-db7b98610108#.cqtliylro) an author talks about 4 steps of rendering:

```
Styles -> Layout -> Paint -> Composite
```

I've read about two stages: `Reflow` and `Repaint`. I'm wondering where those four steps fall under these two stages? I mean, does `reflow` encompass `Styles` and `Layout` steps?

Comment: These are just different names for the same thing by the different browser communities. E.g., reflow in Firefox is the same as layout in Chrome...

Answer (score 2):

I am really not sure what you wanting for an answer but I hope what I mention helps you out in some way.

Reflow encompasses any changes to the layout or a style which may affect the dimensions of an element such as width.

Repaint just deals with visibility and opacity.

**Here are a few good resources to read:**

[10 Ways to Minimize Reflows and improve proformance](https://www.sitepoint.com/10-ways-minimize-reflows-improve-performance/)

[Reflows and Repaints](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/03/27/reflows-repaints-css-performance-making-your-javascript-slow/)

[What every Frontend developer should know about webpage rendering](http://frontendbabel.info/articles/webpage-rendering-101/)

[What forces layout/reflow](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a)

[CSS triggers](https://csstriggers.com/)